# How to create a session cookie in java with path while still having good programming practice of functional programming

Tags: java, functional-programming, immutability

I really like functional programming, I like its immutability concepts and also it's no side-effects concepts for functions.

I'm trying to take some of these concepts into java.

Now I have some kind of a servlet which receives a request and if browser did not send a cookie to server then i would like to create a cookie with a certain path to the user.

now inside the servlet i don't want to hold that logic because its common to multiple servlets.
so i extract it into some kind of a cookie manager which will do that:

CookieManager.java.handleCookies(request, response)

1. Check if browser sent cookie.
2. If not set cookie with new session cookie value with certain path.

however i don't like it because now the servlet will call the CookieManager.java.handleCookie will have a side effect I would rather it to return some kind of a response and further use it in my servlet wihtout having it effect its parameters that i'm passing into it.

anyone can suggest a solution which would both be elegant, no side effects, and excellent in performance?

thanks

Comment: Are you expecting `CookieManager` to just check whether a given cookie exist or not in the request and based on the outcome take action in servlet ?

Comment: exactly! i would want it to be like this however this would impose more code inside the caller! so is it my only choice? if i'm using functional immutable i have a thicker client code? :(?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but by _functional immutable_, you mean any state that `CookieManager` will have ?

Comment: meaning CookieManager will change parameters it gets like if someone calls its method handleCookie it will actually change the response parameter to have a session id if does not exist.

Comment: Not really. Nothing would change inside `CookieManager`. You would pass a cookie string to be detected and request object. `CookieManager ` will simply return `true/false` depending on whether that cookie exists in requests or not. Actual setting of cookie into response will be handled by the Servlet.

Comment: so what if i have multiple servlet that need to set this cookie i would have code duplication.  (filters won't help here because logic inside filters is too much over the "outisde" of the application not internal in it, too tightly coupled with filter api.).

Comment: Well, thats the price of keeping `CookieManager` immutable :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of servlet filter. It would be well suited for your case. You can map your filter to URL pattern and write your code inside dofilter method. Filters are recommended if you want to have pre and post prcoess of request/response. Since you are doing preprocess for you request it would fit in your case. If is also loosely coupled, because you can remove it, modify it, or add another rule anytime without modifying the core servlet code.

Answer (score 0):

One good solution is to use create a servlet which will act as a parent class for all other servlets.
Now in this servlet put this logic of cookie handling in a common function say handlecookie.
In your get and post APIs of this servlet first call this handleCookie and then service API of servlet (keep this empty)

In al child servlet classes you can only override the service class inherited from the parent class and things should work fine for you

[Servlet filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) are other solution that you can make use of.